# Regex for bit string containing at least 2 zeros but no consecutive zeros.

Tags: regular-expressions

This is what I have:

(1*011*011*)*

But I don't think this is accounting for an odd number of zeros, like "10101010101111". I think I have the right expression that satisfies no 2 consecutive zeros and even number of zeros.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get you started.

You need to have two zeroes, so start by putting those in your regex, leaving space between, before and after:

$$
\_\_\_\_\_\_0\_\_\_\_\_\_0\_\_\_\_\_\_
$$
Now, consider the space on the left. Every zero in this region is followed by a $1$. Therefore, this portion can be broken into sums of $(01)$ and $1$, so it is $(01|1)^*$:
$$
(01|1)^*0\_\_\_\_\_\_0\_\_\_\_\_\_
$$
What about the space in the middle? It has similar rules, but we cannot quite use the same regex $(01|1)^*$ we used on the left. The problem is that this can begin with a zero, which would cause a $00$ with the first $0$ we placed. How can you fix this?